# Dynamically changing form in alfresco workflow

Tags: forms, dynamic, workflow, alfresco

Simple explanation of what I am trying to achieve:

I have workflow form with two fields - text field and file upload one. I need to dynamically change text field from not-mandatory to mandatory once there is at least one file selected in file upload field (and back to not-mandatory once file is removed).

There is association in model between fields but I don't see a way to do what I want through that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I answered the same question somewhere, but can't find it any more.

1. You can create one custom form controller, which contains both fields and with client-side JS activate/disable the mandatory marker.
2. You can access any field on the same form with the following `${form.fields.prop_<your field>.id}` Use this with **Dom.get** function to get the field and use it to determine if it's filled.

Comment: Will try this after I finish experimenting with custom validator. Meanwhile I assume there is no examples of your approach?

Comment: Probably there is, but don't know where. I've used this a couple of times, but can't just openly give you the code. Even if I did, it would make less sense than the points I gave you. enabling/disabling a field or making the maker visible is just plain clientside JS knowledge.

Comment: Understandable. I will google out info needed to try out your suggestion. (I don't have experience with alfresco so I am unsure how to put two fields in one i guess .ftl template. Also I have 0 experience with JS. But that's what google is for.)

Comment: Ok, I am attempting your suggestion. Are you sure Alfresco support field controller with more than one field? Older posts say it's not possible and after that there is no info on it (https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/fdk-multiple-value-form-field-how-08072011 ). Normally template is set like "<field id="xx:Number"  set="normal">  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textfield.ftl" >" how one sets same ftl template for both fields?

Comment: Could you at least give me line that makes field mandatory in JS? I can disable fields but setting mandatory with document.getElementById("${args.htmlid}_prop_" + propertyList[0]).mandatory = true; doesn't make field mandatory.

Comment: the way you're using the mandatory won't work. In the other field it's checking on <#if field.mandatory && field.value == ""> which is a server side checking by Freemarker. So change that to a css as style hidden and un-hide it in the other controller.

Comment: Wont that just make field look like mandatory? (as in field will look like mandatory but pressing "start workflow" will continue instead of whining about mandatory field not filled?)

Comment: sure, but that's what you want right? I mean you can't force it to be mandatory. Btw you just brought that up, you didn't specify that in the call. You can play around with share form evaluators which will block the 'save' button, I'm not sure if that will work on the start workflow button.

Comment: Well, I thought "from not-mandatory to mandatory" was obvious. As it wasn't "add '*' next to field title". Eh, this makes my day much harder... Thanks for help. Will look at form evaluators now.